# Unable to visualize OBJ and GLB models using A-Frame library

Tags: javascript, 3d, aframe

I try to visualize models, using A-Frame library. I have a server with static contents (my glb-models) and https connection (to conform to WebXR requirements). However, when the page with the model loads, I see just a blank screen with no graphics and no errors in the console. And DOM structure also looks strange:

[image]

As you can see `gltf-model` property of `a-entity` is blank. And this is the code, that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <title>3D Model</title>
    <script src="/AframeViewer/lib/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
    onload = async () => {
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      const guid = urlParams.get("guid");
      const year = urlParams.get("year");
      const month = urlParams.get("month");
      const extension = urlParams.get("extension");      
      let scene = document.getElementById("scene");
      let assets = document.getElementById("assets");
      if (extension == 'glb' || extension == 'gltf') {
        const asset = document.createElement("a-asset-item");
        asset.setAttribute("id", "base");
        asset.setAttribute("src", `/files/digitaltwineditor/files/${year}/${month}/${guid}.${extension}`);
        assets.appendChild(asset);

        const entity = document.createElement("a-entity");
        entity.setAttribute("gltf-model", "#base");
        scene.appendChild(entity);
      } else if (extension == 'obj') {
        const assetObj = document.createElement("a-asset-item");
        assetObj.setAttribute("id", "obj");
        assetObj.setAttribute("src", `/files/digitaltwineditor/files/${year}/${month}/${guid}.obj`);
        assets.appendChild(assetObj);

        const assetMtl = document.createElement("a-asset-item");
        assetMtl.setAttribute("id", "mtl");
        assetMtl.setAttribute("src", `/files/digitaltwineditor/files/${year}/${month}/${guid}.mtl`);
        assets.appendChild(assetMtl);

        const entity = document.createElement("a-entity");
        entity.setAttribute("obj-model", "obj: #obj; mtl: #mtl");
        scene.appendChild(entity);
      }      
    };
    </script>
    
  </head>    
  <body>
    <a-scene id="scene" background="color: #F3F3F3" renderer="colorManagement: true">
      <a-assets id="assets">
      </a-assets>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see in developer tools, that all files are loaded correctly - that is all those `src` attributes have correct values and files themselves are available.

What may be wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: DOM Inspector is not going to show the component values. Not reflected in DOM for perf reasons. Gotta do `el.getAttribute('gltf-model');` I recommend first creating a scene that loads those models statically and make sure they render. Also in general is hard to help without code people can run and debug. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe to share an example that illustrates your issue